# Is assigning a variable to a control value and then using the variable slower then using the control value directly? (in .NET)

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, variables

Suppose we have 3,800,000 textboxes.
Each textbox contains some word.

we have a function `GenerateIRSTaxCode(string s, string s2, ... string s3800000)`

we have a button that will take these 3.8MM texboxes and pass them into the `GenerateIRSTaxCode()` function.

What will be the difference in performance by doing:

```
string s = textbox1.text;
string s1 = textbox2.text;
...
string s3800000= textbox3800000.text;

GenerateIRSTaxCode(s1, s2, ... s3800000)
```

**VS**

```
 GenerateIRSTaxCode(textbox1.text, textbox2.text, ... textbox3800000.text)
```

EDIT:

So I've done some testing:

```
  {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {

                DateTime starttime1 = DateTime.Now;
                List<string> words = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
                {
                    string s = textBox2.Text;
                    words.Add(s);

                }
                DateTime endtime1 = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime starttime2 = DateTime.Now;

                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4000000; i2++)
                {
                    words.Add(textBox2.Text);

                }
                DateTime endtime2 = DateTime.Now;

                TimeSpan elapsed1 = endtime1 - starttime1;
                TimeSpan elapsed2 = endtime2 - starttime2;
                TimeSpan performancehit = elapsed1 - elapsed2;


                textBox1.AppendText("Assign Time start: " + starttime1 + "\r\nAssign Time End: " + endtime1 + "\r\n elapsed time: " + elapsed1.ToString() +
                    "\r\n NoAssign Time start: " + starttime2 + "\r\nNoAssign Time End: " + endtime2 + "\r\n elapsed time: " + elapsed2.ToString() +"\r\n Performance Hit: " + performancehit.ToString());

            }

            textBox1.AppendText("Performance Complete");
        }
```

My results:

Assign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:39:19 PM Assign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:39:32 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6545000  NoAssign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:39:32 PM NoAssign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:39:46 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6080000
Performance Hit: 00:00:00.0465000

Assign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:39:46 PM Assign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:40:00 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.7054000  NoAssign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:40:00 PM NoAssign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:40:13 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6400000 
 Performance Hit: 00:00:00.0654000

Assign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:40:13 PM Assign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:40:27 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6434000  NoAssign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:40:27 PM NoAssign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:40:41 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.7122000
Performance Hit:
-00:00:00.0688000

Assign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:40:41 PM Assign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:40:54 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6544000  NoAssign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:40:54 PM NoAssign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:41:08 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6342000
Performance Hit: 00:00:00.0202000

Assign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:41:08 PM Assign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:41:22 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6788000  NoAssign Time start: 12/28/2011 9:41:22 PM NoAssign Time End: 12/28/2011 9:41:35 PM  elapsed time: 00:00:13.6754000

Performance Hit: 00:00:00.0034000

Performance Complete

So it looks like there is a hit. However in the 3rd run - it was faster the other way.
Perhaps something else was running on my pc for that time that may have affected this?

EDIT2

Doing some more digging on this. Found a very good article by Charlie Calvert here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/10/11/optimizing-c_2300_-string-performance.aspx

This has to do with the fact that

> C# maintains something called an "intern table." This is a list of
>   strings that are currently referenced. If a new string is created with
>   code like that shown in lines 18 and 19, then the intern table is
>   checked. If your string is already in there, then both variables will
>   point at the same block of memory maintained by the intern table. The
>   string is not duplicated.

I would gather that assuming the textbox data is stored as a string, and both my s1 and textbox1.text strings are the same, they will be referencing the same place in the memory. 
So at least we are not taking a hit on the memory.

Comment: Have you tried creating 3.8 million textboxes and measuring?

Comment: You have a function with 4 million arguments? I'm impressed.

Comment: :) this is a theoretical question.

Comment: There is a trade-off here, readability vs. performance. The performance hit can only be guessed at until you write the code and benchmark it!

Comment: Sadly a rather dubious benchmark - at best. REad [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) first.. yes it's java, yes basically the same thing's apply still

Comment: Closed as NC until you've performed some benchmarks (not necessarily 3.8M, but something with a large number of textboxes).

Comment: I'm probably just a sample of one, but I don't like to create any more text boxes or other controls than can be visible at one time to a person looking at a display screen. Of course, that's the default behavior of *[differential execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/differential-execution)*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a 0.5% performance hit (0.0688 seconds out of 13.6 total seconds) is not worth reducing readability and maintainability by removing variables, even 3.8MM of them :).